# Why does console.log(typeof 4+5) return number5 in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why does this code return number5 in js? I can't figure it out.
`console.log(typeof 4+5)`

Comment: `typeof 4` is the string `"number"`. So, `"number" + 5` is `"number5"`. Operator precedence.

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof (4 + 5))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In official documentation of [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), it's clearly stated that:

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

So what your are calculating is something like that `String+Number` which in every case will cause a [`String Concatenation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat). Remember when there is an add operation with two operands and one of them is a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), it will always end up with string concatenation.